# Python3 concurrent future doesn't seem to work async

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I'm new to python and just trying a simple threading example. But I can't explain myself why this code is working synchronous:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

def return_after_3_secs():
    time.sleep(3)
    return

def callback_method(future):
    print ("Hello World.")

with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as pool:
    future = pool.submit(return_after_3_secs)
    future.add_done_callback(callback_method)

print ("1")
time.sleep(1)
print ("2")
time.sleep(1)
print ("3")

print (future.result())
```

I'm basically from C# and thinking of a future as a `Task` in C#. So this is a handle or token for the new Thread.

I would expect following output:

> 1. 1
> 2. 2
> 3. 3
> 4. Hello World.
> 5. None

But I'm getting:

> 1. Hello World.
> 2. 1
> 3. 2
> 4. 3
> 5. None

Before something is printed the Console wait for 3 seconds. So this code is running synchron. Can someone help me up with the understanding of futures and tell me why the `time.sleep(3)` isn't running on second thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statements after the `with ThreadPoolExecutor(..)` is executed after the statements inside the `with ..` statements done.

(because `with ThreadPoolExecutor(..)` internally calls `executor.shutdown(wait=True)` to wait the pending futures done, and related resources freed. See [`concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown))

By indenting those statement (`print`, `time.sleep`) inside the `with` statement, you will get what you want.

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as pool:
    future = pool.submit(return_after_3_secs)
    future.add_done_callback(callback_method)

    print ("1")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("2")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("3")
```

Comment: @Sebi, No problem. Happy Python hacking!